# Quais os requisitos necessário para executar um programa feito em C# na maquina de um cliente?

Tags: c#

Estou testando o meu aplicativo feito em `c#` na maquina do cliente, ele funciona normalmente, o meu problema só esta em imprimir os relatório, ao imprimir esta gerar este erro:

```
Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento no aplicativo. Se você clicar em
continuar, o aplicativo ignorá esse erro e tentara continuar. S e Clicar
em Encerrar, o aplicativo será incerrado imediatamente.

Não foi possivel carregar arquivo ou assembly
"Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms, Version=11.0.0.0 Culture=neutral.
PublicKey Token=89845dcd8080cc91" ou uma de suas dependências.
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado.
```

Antes de eu ter executado o meu aplicativo, instalei na maquina do cliente os seguintes software:

- Sql_server 2008 R2;
- ReportViewer 2008;
- NET.Framework_3.5_Windows_8.1;
- VisualBasicPowerPacksSetup;

Mas mesmo assim ele não emite o relatório.

Comment: Verifique a plataforma do reportviewer 64/32 bits. Eu não o utilizo, mas no Crystal reports tem essa diferença. Você pode no seu projeto, colocar a referência para copiar para o diretório de saída também, e mandar a dll junto da aplicação

Comment: Quanto aos bits. já verifiquei é de 32.

Comment: você instalou isso: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6576 ??

Comment: Sim instalei, na descrição da questão em causa, consta todos os programas que instalei para  a maquina do cliente

Comment: sim, só perguntei pra conferir se é o mesmo descrito

Comment: Certifique-se que a(s) DLL(s) do ReportViewer está(ão) no PATH do cliente ou no gac.

Answer (score 1):

tente fazer isso:

Na opção "Copy Local" marque como true, e compile o projeto

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: ok, vou testar, gratos pela ajuda.

Comment: Acabei de testar e não resultou

Answer (score 0):

Como disse que instalou o [Microsoft Report Viewer Redistributable 2008](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6576) então precisa apenas copiar para o *Bin* do seu aplicativo as seguintes DLL:

```
• Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll
• Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization.dll
• Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll
• Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll
• Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll
```

Caminho do GAC

> Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll

```
C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common\11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91
```

> Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization.dll

```
C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization\11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91
```

> Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll

```
C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel\11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91
```

> Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll <- se a aplicação for Web

```
C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms\11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91
```

> Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll <- se a aplicação for WINDOWS FORM

```
C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms\11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91
```

> Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll

```
C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types\11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91
```

Comment: Mesmo fazendo assim não resulta, instalei o ReportView versão 11.0.0.0 que ele esta a pedir na mensagem de erro e não funciona.

Comment: E encontrou os arquivos que comentei acima?

Comment: Veja que na mensagem de erro apresentada na pergunta existe um token '89845dcd8080cc91', observe que deve existir uma pasta com o mesmo nome. Encontrou também?

Comment: Eu também faria o uninstall e install do [Microsoft Report Viewer Redistributable 2008](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6576)

Comment: Já consegui resolver o meu problema, instalei o SQLSysClrTypes2012_x64 acompanhado do ReportViewer, mas antes desinstalei o reportview que eu havia instalado.

Comment: @AntónioMateta legal que resolveu, vou votar positivo na sua pergunta!